# what the difference between 'devtool build-image <image>' and 'bitbake <image>'

Tags: embedded, yocto, bitbake

what the difference between 'devtool build-image ' and 'bitbake '

I'm working with `rocko` branch. I use the regular way to build image via:

```
bitbake core-image-full-cmdline
```

All works fine!

But now I'm trying to work with `devtool` [tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiD7rB35CRE&t=1348s) and then I need to use another way to build the core image:

```
devtool build-image core-image-full-cmdline
```

So, what's the difference?

Comment: Well, it seems the only difference is that `devtool build-image` also builds an image including the workspace recipes... Reference [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/sites/default/files/yocto_devday_advanced_class_berlin_1.pdf).

Comment: E.g., I do 'devtool add' or 'devtool modify' - now I *must* use 'devtool build-image' to include the added (or modified) recipe.

Comment: Also, devtool is used in eSDK (Extensible SDK).